# Why static_cast conversion from base to derived works inside base but not outside

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion, static-cast

**Why static_case conversion from base class to derived works inside base class, but doesn't work outside the base class**

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

class Base
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    int getValue() const { return static_cast<const T&>(*this).getValue(); }
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    Derived(int v): value(v) { }
    int getValue() const { return value; }
    int value;
};

class Another
{
    int getValue() const { return 5; }
};

template <typename T>
void out(const Base & base) {
    cout << base.getValue<T>() << '\n';
}

int main() {
    Derived d(5);
    Base b;
    out<Derived>(d);    //understandable, d has derived part.
    out<Derived>(b);   //don't understand, b is only base.
    out<Another>(b);    //compile time error   
    //static_cast<Derived>(b);   //compile time error
}
```

I read [this](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/05/12/curiously-recurring-template-pattern/) article about CRTP and stumble upon this code:

```
template <typename T>
class Base
{
public:
    void doSomething()
    {
        T& derived = static_cast<T&>(*this);
        use derived...
    }
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
    ...
};
```

And I do not clearly understand how conversion works here too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `static_cast` conversion shall be used only if this conversion is legal. In your code you are creating an object of class `Base`, and you are trying to convert it to the class `Derived`. Luckily to you the implementation of the `Derived::getValue()` doesn't use any data members, and returns a value from literal. Anyway that is undefined behavior.

In case of CRTP no instance of `Base` class is created: only instances of the `Derived` are used.

**Upd.** Try this:

```
//static_cast<Derived>(b);   doesn't compile
static_cast<Derived&>(b);   shall compile
```

**Upd 2.** You get junk because the `Derived::getValue()` uses a data member (in your initial version of code data members were not used).

Comment: I edited the code snippet. Please concretize your answer. I'm confused with the fact that static_cast does not cause any compile time errors

Comment: So, actually CRTP means casting to derived type to use part of its implementation, and static_cast is just a piece of implementation, not a feature? Just base class that uses derived class implementation?

Comment: @АлександрКушниренко I'm not sure what you mean by "not a feature", but yes, this is the part of the implementation. That would work only if `Derived` actually inherits from the `Base<Derived>`.

Comment: @Dmitty Kuzminov Thank you very much, I appreciate your patience. I figured out this concept, just misinterpreted static_cast as a "thin" implementation technique.

Answer (score 1):

Last cast in main() is incorrect syntactically and not equivalent to code in template, you can't upcast object to object (you can downcast through, causing type contraction). In templates above you cast references.

`Derived&` can be bound to `Base&`, `static_cast` have no way to check it. CRTP ensures it, because `this` point at storage of Derived type, `*this` results in reference that can be safely cast to `Derived&` reference object.

Reference to `Another` can't be bound to reference to `Base`, when `Base` is not base class of `Another`. In that case casting pointers or references using `static_cast` is illegal.

Template code is legal, in case of CRTP works because template code is instatiated where Derived is comlete enough type, i.e. where template was used. Template itself doesn't generate anything and isn't compiled, only checked for correctness.

Still, in CRTP some things won't be possible, e.g. to use inside of Base class nested type declarations from Derived class as complete types, for a simple reason : they are not complete and are not subject for forward lookup, unlike member variables and functions. If such use required, then a third type has to be defined before Base, contsining required declarations.

Comment: No, the program compiles and outputs. I don't understand why this conversion is possible inside the Base class but outside it is illegal.

Comment: @АлександрКушниренко you didn't understood me. It's not inside or outside class, it's difference between template and non-template context. and the second attemt to cast  Base to Derived result in reading illegal memory storage, while last one is outright illegal because you are trying to upcast automatic object to object, npt a reference to reference

Comment: third attempt causes compile error, but second doesn't and I don't understand the reason.

Comment: @АлександрКушниренко reason is that Base is not Derived.

Comment: Base is not Another, but out<Another> is a compile error, and out<Derived> compiles and gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: Derived is Base, Another is not Base, so reference binding is not possible, static_cast won't be legal. Technically, in standard it said Base is subobject of Derived, but pointers to them are equivalent

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the rules of C++. `static_cast` can be used to convert a base class expression to derived class.  If , at runtime, the object is not actually a base class subobject of a derived class object then it is undefined behaviour with no diagnostic required.

The first sentence of your question is incorrect,  this cast can be written at any point of the code.

`out<Another>()` fails to compile because `Another` is not related by inheritance to `Base`.